# Catching multiple exceptions and passing to custom Exception handler using Python

Tags: python, exception

I'm writing some python code using imapclient module and would like to catch it's exceptions and add some messaging to them. I know the module has the following exceptions: socket.error, socket.gaierror, IMAP4.error, IMAP4.abort, IMAP4.readonly

First, do people generally put their custom exceptions in a separate module and import them, to keep code clear and clean? If no, why not?

Second, knowing what the exceptions that this module has, I'm not exactly sure how to catch all of them, and then decipher which exception was caught and handle it appropriately with a custom exception class. Allowing me to add addition messaging or whatever I might want to do.

Third, Would I have one 'MyException' class that could have different logic for each one of the five exceptions that I might be expecting and passing in?

My first poor attempt:

```
def some_func():
    try:
        login(email, password)
        print "logged into account as: %s " %email
    except Exception, e:
        raise MyException, e

class MyException(Exception):
    if Exception == socket.error:
        print 'Additional messaging here'
    elif Exception == something.else:
        do this
```

Comment: Your question is somewhat unclear.  What are you intending the code inside `MyException` to do?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a beginner. Bare with me, I'm trying to pass the caught exception into MyException class. Then my exception handler will determine which of the five exceptions that I'm expecting, and add some print statement to it.

Comment: I've given an answer below.  Why are you catching all Exceptions and then passing them to MyException?  Usually it's better to catch specific exceptions and then, if necessary, raise a custom exception for each one.

Comment: No particular reason other than I don't know best practices/ what makes sense and trying to learn. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you really want to do this, the way you would usually do it is to check your various conditions at the place where the exception is *raised*, and use that information to raise the right exception.  Roughly:

```
# base class for your custom exceptions
class MyException(Exception):
    pass

# class to wrap socket error
class MySocketException(MyException):
    pass

# class for some other exception
class MyOtherException(MyException):
    pass

def some_func():
    try:
        login(email, password)
        print "logged into account as: %s " %email
    except socket.error:
        raise MySocketException, "My custom socket error message"
    except SomeOtherException:
        raise MyOtherException, "My custom error message"
```

This gets at your question about "catching all of them and deciphering which one".  The way to do that is to use multiple `except` clauses, one for each kind of exception (or group of kinds of exception) you want to handle together.  Then, in each except clause, do what you want to do to handle those exceptions.  This is better than catching them all in one big `except` clause and trying to split them out later.  Part of the point of using `except` is that it lets you specify just what kinds of exception you want to catch.

However, you should think about why you're doing this.  There's not much use in replacing a normal exception like `socket.error` with a custom exception class that only replaces that one kind of error.  In that case, why not just catch and handle `socket.error` directly?  You would usually create exception classes for kinds of errors that are specific to your program.

As for your side question about whether people put exceptions in a separate module, that's up to you.  In general, you should split things into separate modules when it becomes unwieldy to keep them all in the same module.  If your module is small and defines only a few Exception classes, there's usually no need to make a separate module for them.  If the module is large and has a complicated hierarchy of exceptions, you may want to split them into a separate module.

Answer (score 0):

> First, do people generally put their custom exceptions in a separate
>   module and import them, to keep code clear and clean? If no, why not?

Depends. Usually, if a custom exception type is closely related to the code in the current module (which it often is), then it makes most sense to define it there.

> Second, knowing what the exceptions that this module has, I'm not
>   exactly sure how to catch all of them, and then decipher which
>   exception was caught and handle it appropriately with a custom
>   exception class.

You do not need a custom exception class. Something like this would work:

```
try:
    ...
except (Exception1, Exception2, Exception3) as e:
    if isinstance(e, ...):
        do_this()
    elif isinstance(e, ...):
        do_that()
    else:
        do_something_else()
```

Of course you can further abstract this with custom error types, but you did not explain why you need them.

> Third, Would I have one 'MyException' class that could have different
>   logic for each one of the five exceptions that I might be expecting
>   and passing in?

That depends. I am still not convinced what for you need a custom error class. If it is about sharing code, you could easily write

```
try:
    ...
except (Exception1, Exception2, Exception3) as e:
    handle_exception(e)
```

and then just define a useful function `handle_exception(e)` and call it from various places.

Comment: It's rather awkward to catch three kinds of exceptions and then split them out with `isinstance`.  Instead, just have three separate `except` clauses that catch one type each, and have the `do_this` and `do_that` in the different `except` clauses.

Comment: @BrenBarn catching the exception tuple is the shortest possible way for "I'm not exactly sure how to catch all of them". In the example I am just giving ideas...

Comment: @Jan-Philip Gehrcke thank you for directly answering each one of my questions. I accepted the other one only because it was first and helped me.

Comment: It's fine :) but upvoting does not hurt if the answer has helped :)